# Mysql Query comparing 2 variables

Tags: mysql

I am doing a query and need some assistance.

Here is part of the query:

```
AND count_sub>2 AND count_del<=2
```

What I want to do is, take the 2 variables in this query and IF `count_sub` is greater than `5+count_del` continue.

Example:

```
count_sub = 10
count_del = 4
```

The difference is 6 so that would return results, but if:

```
count_sub = 4
count_del = 1
```

The difference is 3 and that would not return anything

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can just query the difference:

```
WHERE count_sub - count_del > 5
```

Comment: You could also do something like `WHERE (case when count_sub > count_del+5 then 1 else 0) = 1`, although for a simple greater than calculation it's overkill.

Comment: -1 You should avoid arithmetic operators on the `WHERE` clause column. It prevents the use of indices.

Comment: @njk I think a -1 is a little harsh, but it's your choice. Can you point out an alternative for my own benefit?

Comment: @MathieuImbert See my answer. Your feedback is welcome. I may not be applying the concept appropriately in this case.

Comment: here is the full query.. its a bit confusing for me..                      $sql_query="SELECT a.id_user as userid,a.id as mid,a.url as murl ,urlid from automatic_url a,ft_search f where f.del=0 AND count_sub>2 AND count_del<=2 AND del!=1 AND a.id_user=f.id_user AND urlid=f.id order by a.id_user";

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend the following solution:

```
SELECT a.id
FROM tbl1 a
INNER JOIN (SELECT id, count_sub - count_del AS diff FROM tbl1) b ON b.id = a.id
WHERE b.diff > 5
```

By using arithmetic in the `WHERE` clause (`WHERE count_sub - count_del > 5`
), you prevent the optimizer from using the index on the column. The general rule is to move the arithmetic as far away from there `WHERE` clause as possible. It is more efficient to move the arithmetic to a derived table to derived column.